# How to force the designer to redraw the re-sizing rectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a custom user control that when an item is dropped into it, it will be re-positioned (kinda like a Java-FX VBox). This works great, but when the item is moved, the re-sizing rectangle is not updated.

Example:

[image: Re-sizing rectangle not moved.]

How do I force the designer to redraw the re-sizing rectangle?

**Edit:** Just to avoid any confusion, I'm referring to the re-sizing rectangle in Visual Studio while in design mode, not something I've programmed.

Comment: @Tigran, The buttons are added as a child control, then I _immediately_ update its location. Although, maybe I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you provide a simple code snippet?

Comment: @Tigran, the re-sizing rectangle? How would I get a reference to it?

Comment: oh, ok. I miised resizing. so which item is moved ?

Comment: In my picture, I have dragged "button4" into my custom control (and placed it where the re-sizing rectangle appears). My control moved it down so that it is stacked properly. I'm just wondering how I can force VS's designer to refresh the re-sizing rectangle.

Comment: FYI, java-fx is a poorly designed, lacking, oracle-quality imitation of WPF. in .Net, You're much better off just using WPF instead of reinventing the wheel and trying to get decent UI features out of winforms.

Comment: @HighCore, I don't have that option.

Comment: if the dimmension of the button is standart, and new button appears *always* on the bottom of the button's list, you may want to look on Anchor property of the rectangle. So rectangle will be "gluwed" to the bottom border of the user control, with some offset. Don't remember exact property parameters, but "play" with them to achieve desired effect. that pretty much the way to manage that kind of situation.

Comment: @Tigran, I have no idea how to access a reference to VS's design time re-sizing rectangle.

Comment: If rectangle you add in desifn time, go ti its properties and find Anchor

Comment: It's not a rectangle I add. It is the rectangle that appears when you click on a control. It is part of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share your ControlDesigner code, but after the control is resized, try telling the designer that things need to be updated:

```
this.BehaviorService.SyncSelection();
```